# Simple Java caching library or design pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns, caching, memcached, ehcache

I need to frequently access the result of a time-consuming calculation. The result changes infrequently, so I have to recalculate the data from time to time but it is ok to use the outdated result for a while. What would be the easiest way to do this and is there an existing library method or design pattern?

I am thinking of something like

```
private static List myCachedList = null;

...

// refresh list once in 3600 seconds
if (needsRefresh(myCachedList, 3600)) {
    // run the calculation
    myCachedList = ...
}
// use either updated or previous value from here on
```

A proper implementation might not be trivial, it might have to deal with thread safety, race conditions etc., so I would rather use a proven implementation than roll my own here.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Congratulations for realising that writing your own can be more trouble it initially appears!

I would check out the [Guava cache](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained) solution. Guava is a proven library and the caches are easily available (and configurable) via a fluent factory API.

> All Guava caches, loading or not, support the method get(K,
>   Callable<V>). This method returns the value associated with the key in
>   the cache, or computes it from the specified Callable and adds it to
>   the cache. No observable state associated with this cache is modified
>   until loading completes. This method provides a simple substitute for
>   the conventional "if cached, return; otherwise create, cache and
>   return" pattern.

Answer (score 3):

I would take a look at Google [guava-libraries](https://github.com/google/guava/).  Much of this work has already been done for you.

There's specifically a section called Timed Eviction, which might be related to what you want.  https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained#timed-eviction

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest for you to use the Proxy Design Pattern
that way you can encapsulate the caching logic-implementation in your proxy class

theres a cool example here that looks like to fit your needs

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern

Answer (score 0):

if you do not want to use third party library, simply you can create a static map which holds the key and value. using key you can retrieve the data fast.

and write methods to add values to cache, get, remove.

```
public SimpleCache{
    private static Map<String,Object> simpleCache = new HashMap<>();

    public static <T> T getValue(String key, Class type){

    //todo check contains here, if map doesn't contains key, throw not found exception

    Object val = simpleCache.get(key);

    return (T)val;    
  }
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: And where is the eviction? This cache will grow and grow until an OutOfMemoryError?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [SimplCache](https://github.com/lekhana3003/SimplCache), it accepts implementation of Cache DB and persistent DB to provide an easy implementation for Cache system.